# How can import data into kaggle kernel if the folder is zipped?

Tags: import, kaggle

I facing problem importing data into kaggle kernel from "../input/train/filename". it's throwing an error saying directory doesn't exist. I guess this is happening because the 'train' is a zipped folder. Any solution?

Comment: Attaching a screenshot could help us better understand the problem.

Comment: I will do shortly.

Answer (score 1):

To see what's in your `../input/` directory (where datasets you attach to your kernel are located), run `!find ../input/` in a code cell. This will print all paths to dataset files. You should see that the uncompressed directories and files are accessible.

If this doesn't help, perhaps you can share more details to help reproduce your issue (e.g., a link to the dataset and/or your kernel).

Comment: In the input directory the data set is present in a zipped folder. It contains images. To use it in kaggle kernel, I need to unzip it. I can alternatively download the data set unzip it and use it in my local system but I want to use the kaggle kernel to train my model( as it has higher graphics memory)